# Every Lévy Process satisfies the markov property?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Is it true that if $\{X_t\}_{t\geq0}$ is a Lévy Process then it also satisfy the markov property?

Comment: Yes. The fact that they have independent increments can help you to deduce that.

Comment: In fact Levy processes possess the strong Markov property: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2098683/strong-markov-property-for-levy-processes